# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot{(x)}\ln^4\cot\frac{x}{2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral ?:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\left(\, x\,\right)\ln^{4}\left[\,\cot\left(\,{x \over 2}\,\right)\,\right]\,{\rm d}x
$$
It seems that evaluate to
$$
{\pi \over 16}\left[\,
5\pi^{4}\ln\left(\, 2\,\right) - 6\pi^{2}\zeta\left(\, 3\,\right)
-{93 \over 4}\,\zeta\left(\, 5\,\right)
\,\right]
$$
Exactly ?.

Comment: May I ask how you obtained this result ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Most likely WolframAlpha.

Comment: I would be quite surprized ... but you may be right ! Cheers :-)

Comment: A simple Weierstrass substitution gives
$$I=2\int^1_0\frac{\arctan{x}\ln^4{x}}{x}{\rm d}x-4\int^1_0\frac{x\arctan{x}\ln^4{x}}{1+x^2}\ {\rm d}x$$
Hence everything gets reduced to the same old story of evaluating some Euler sums.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$J = \int_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan x{{\ln }^4}x}}{x}dx} \qquad K = \int_0^1  {\frac{x{\arctan x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}$$
Then by M.N.C.E.'s comment, $$\tag{1}I = \int_0^{\pi /2} {x\cot x{{\ln }^4}\left( {\cot \frac{x}{2}} \right)dx} = 2J - 4K$$

---

Here is a symmetry of the integrand that we can exploit:
$$\begin{aligned}
K &= \int_0^1 {\frac{{x\arctan x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}  
\\&= \int_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan x{{\ln }^4}x}}{x}dx}  - \int_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}dx} 
\\&= J - \int_1^\infty  {\frac{{x\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \arctan x} \right){{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx} 
\\& = J - \int_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{x}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \arctan x} \right){{\ln }^4}xdx}  + \int_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \arctan x} \right){{\ln }^4}xdx} 
\\& = J - J + \frac{\pi }{2}\int_1^\infty  {\frac{{{{\ln }^4}x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}dx}  - \int_1^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx} 
\\&= \frac{\pi }{2}\int_0^1 {\frac{{x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}  - \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx}  + \int_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx}
\\& = \frac{\pi }{2}\int_0^1 {\frac{{x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}  - \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx}  + \int_0^1 {\frac{{{{\ln }^4}x\arctan x}}{x}dx}  - \int_0^1 {\frac{{x{{\ln }^4}x\arctan x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}
\\& = \frac{\pi }{4}\int_0^1 {\frac{{x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}  - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx}  + \frac{J}{2} \end{aligned}$$
**The fact that exponent $4$ is even is paramount here.**
Plugging into $(1)$, the $J$ miraculously cancelled:
$$I = 2\underbrace{\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan x}}{{x(1 + {x^2})}}{{\ln }^4}xdx}}_{L}  - \pi \underbrace{\int_0^1 {\frac{{x{{\ln }^4}x}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx}}_{45\zeta(5)/64} $$

---

The crux of the problem is, indeed, evaulating the remaining integral.
Note that $$ L = \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {x\cot x{{\ln }^4}(\tan x)dx} $$ and we have the following formula:

> For $-2<p<1$, $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {x{{\tan }^p}xdx}  = \frac{\pi
>  }{4}\csc \frac{{p\pi }}{2}\left[ {\psi ( - \frac{p}{2} + 1) - 2\psi (
>  - p + 1) - \gamma } \right]$$

Hence the value of $L$ follows from it by differentiating four times and set $p=-1$:
$$L = -\frac{3 \pi ^3 \zeta (3)}{16}-\frac{3 \pi  \zeta (5)}{8}+\frac{5}{32} \pi ^5 \ln 2$$

Finally, we obtain $$I = 2L - \pi \frac{45\zeta(5)}{64} = \color{blue}{-\frac{3 \pi ^3 \zeta (3)}{8}-\frac{93 \pi  \zeta (5)}{64}+\frac{5}{16} \pi ^5 \ln 2}$$

Comment: Very well, thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

> *`How to evaluate the following integral ?`*

Using *M.N.C.E.*'s hints, rewrite his first integral in terms of $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5x}{1+x^2}dx$ using integration by parts with regard to $\dfrac{dx}x=d\big(\ln x\big)$, then expand $\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and switch the order of summation and integration. This will yield a very familiar [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). Similar tricks apply for the second one as well, only first rewrite $\ln^4x$ as $\bigg[\dfrac{d^4}{dn^4}x^n\bigg]_{\large n=0}\quad$ and then switch the order of integration and differentiation. Once again, you will encounter a very familiar series.

Comment: As usual, the $x$-factor is the big problem.

Comment: In what way? Why would it?

Comment: Because $x$ becomes 'ugly' under the usual variable changes ( trig, Weiertrass, log , etc...). Don't worry about it. Go ahead.

Comment: @pisco125: Not quite sure what's so *messy* about $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigg(\frac{H_k}2-H_{2k}\bigg)~\big(-x^2\big)^k ~=~ \frac{x~\arctan x}{1+x^2},$$ or about XPaul's answer, for that matter; after all, as MNCE said from the start, it all *gets reduced to the same old story of evaluating some [Euler sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer and I need more work. Denote the original integral by $I$. From M.N.C.E's idea, define
$$ I_1=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln^4x}{x}dx, I_2(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x\arctan(a x)\ln^4x}{1+x^2}dx $$
and then $I_2(0)=0$ and $I=2I_1-4I_2(1)$. Now
\begin{eqnarray}
I_1&=&-\frac15\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ln^5xdx\\
&=&-\frac15\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}\ln^5xdx\\
&=&\frac{120}5\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}\\
&=&\frac{120}5\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+1)^6}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+3)^6}\right)\\
&=&\frac{3}{512}(\zeta(6,\frac14)-\zeta(6,\frac34)).
\end{eqnarray}
From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), we have
$$ \zeta(6,\frac14)+\zeta(6,\frac24)+\zeta(6,\frac34)=(4^6-1)\zeta(6)=\frac{13\pi^6}{3},\zeta(6,\frac24)=\frac{\pi^6}{15} $$
or
$$ \zeta(6,\frac14)=\frac{64\pi^6}{15}-\zeta(6,\frac34). $$ 
Thus
$$ I_1= \frac{3}{512}(\frac{64\pi^6}{15}-2\zeta(6,\frac34)).$$
But
\begin{eqnarray}
I_2'(a)&=&\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln^4x}{(1+a^2x^2)(1+x^2)}dx\\
&=&\frac1{1-a^2}\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1+a^2x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\ln^4xdx\\
&=&\frac1{1-a^2}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(a^{2n}-1)x^{2n}\ln^4xdx\\
&=&\frac{24}{1-a^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(a^{2n}-1)\frac{1}{(2n+1)^5}\\
&=&-24\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1+a^2+(a^2)^2+\cdots+(a^2)^{n-1})\frac{1}{(2n+1)^5}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I_2(1)&=&-24\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1+a^2+(a^2)^2+\cdots+(a^2)^{n-1})\frac{1}{(2n+1)^5}da\\
&=&-24\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)\frac{1}{(2n+1)^5}\\
&=&-24\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(H_{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2}H_{n}-\frac{1}{2n+1})\frac{1}{(2n+1)^5}\\
&=&-24(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^5}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^5}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^6})\\
&=&-24(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^5}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^5})+\frac{3}{512}(\zeta(6,\frac14)-\zeta(6,\frac34))\\
&=&-24(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^5}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{(2n+1)^5})+\frac{3}{512}(\frac{64\pi^6}{15}-2\zeta(6,\frac34))
\end{eqnarray}